# How to disable direct access to web resources for ASP.NET MVC projectcs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a web site that runs on ASP.NET MVC. I have of course disabled the directory browsing. I have also added conditions to my `RouteConfig.cs` file to accept only pages that I want to.

For example:

- `example.com/`
- `example.com/account/login`
- `example.com/account/register`

I also tested that my configs are not accessible directly:

- `example.com/web.config` ---> error 404

However, I still can directly access files under content folder and they are not even minified or anything:

- `example.com/Content/css/style.css` -----> 200:Ok
- `example.com/Content/scripts/myscript.js` ----> 200:ok

Now I see in some articles they recommend adding the following to the `web.config` file:

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

But then it blocks the whole site.

I am sure there should be an easy way to handle this. I use Visual Studio to publish it to a machine running IIS.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be fixed? Thank you.

Comment: "I still can directly access files under content folder", so what's wrong with that? The entire HTML/CSS ecosystem relies on those files to be visible to everyone, and there is nothing to be fixed. If you come from desktop app development and just get started on web development, embrace such key differences and keep learning.

Comment: I was under the impression that the whole idea of bundling is to minify and uglify the content data (including scripts) and let the web server serve it as part of page construction. So Why should that folder be visible at all?

Comment: Then have you configured minification? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Yes. That works all well. If I view page source and click on the link for each resource I see minified version. So I am sure we need to remove access to the content folder. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to use url rewrite to block access:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. That worked. I didn't go directly to IIS. I configured your suggestion using web.config file in the root of my project. Now the Content folder and some others are inaccessible directly but the site works fine. I will add a solution below with the rules. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per @samwu's response above, I constructed the below rules to block folders such as Content, Scripts and logs from direct access but still let the site be functional:

```
    <system.webServer>
        .......
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!--Rules to block direct access to folders and their files. (e.g: https://mysite/Content/CSS/Common.css)-->
            <rule name="Block Content Folder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Content/(.*)$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access to this resource is forbidden."/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="Block Scripts Folder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Scripts/(.*)$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access to this resource is forbidden."/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="Block App_Data Folder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^App_Data/(.*)$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access to this resource is forbidden."/>
            </rule>

            <rule name="Block Logs Folder" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^logs/(.*)$"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access to this resource is forbidden."/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    .......
    </system.webServer>
```