# How to hide the folders dynamically on web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I want to hide the following directories, added the following in my web.config to issue a "404 - Not Found" response status code instead of "403 - Forbidden"

```
     <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments>
                <add segment="Images" />
                <add segment="Scripts" />
                <add segment="Resources" />
                <add segment="Content" />
            </hiddenSegments>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

**Is there any way to handle the folders dynamically**

Comment: What is your purpose of hiding the folder? If only hide this file-list page, then you need to disable directory browsing. if not, you can also try to use the url rewrite: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/76676958/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76676958/13336642).

Comment: @samwu Need to prevent the site structure from being exposed, so would like to hide these folders dynamically in web config

Comment: @samwu  <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />  not working,

Comment: This should work, but you can also set permissions for these files so that users don’t have access. Click on your website in the sites and right-click find switch to the content view, you can see your website documents and then edit the permissions for the file. You can directly select the hidden option in the attributes. In this way, the visiting user will not be able to see it.